# Importing data from HDFS to Hive table

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hive

I have my data in data/2011/01/13/0100/file in HDFS, each of thes file contain data in tab separated, say name, ip , url.

I want to create a table in Hive and import the data from hdfs, table should contain time,name, ip and url.

How can I import these using Hive ? r the data should be in some other format so that I can import the time as well ?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626789/how-can-i-partition-a-table-with-hive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you have to use partitions, read more about them here:

- http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hive/LanguageManual/DDL#Add_Partitions
- [partition column in hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316960/partition-column-in-hive)

Answer (score 4):

You need to create the table to load the files into and then use the LOAD DATA command to load the files into the Hive tables. See the [Hive documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hive/GettingStarted#DDL_Operations) for the precise syntax to use.

Regards,
Jeff

Answer (score 0):

You can create an external table for such data.

Something like:

> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE log_data (name STRING, ip STRING, url STRING)
>   PARTITIONED BY (year BIGINT, month BIGINT, day BIGINT, hour BIGINT)
>   row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' stored as TEXTFILE
>   location 'data'